# Get tag name and tag slug after creating tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get **tag name** and **tag slug** after creating a tag in Wordpress.

I have done this in `function.php`, its working but it just returns `"post_tag"` in `$tags`, and I need to create tag name and slug in return or by any other method.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
function update_tags($tags) {
    $data = array("name" => $tags->name,"slug" => $tags->slug,); 

    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

    $ch = curl_init('APIURL');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
add_action( 'post_tag_add_form', 'update_tags',10 ,1 );
```